# Progress dialog in async task not dismissed while control goes to broadcast receiver

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I am starting progress dialog in my async task pre-execute, meanwhile if i get broadcast and if i perform some time consuming action within Broadcast Receiver , progress dialog is not getting dismissed.Async task is independent of broadcast receiver.Thank you in advance.Any help is appreciated.

```
class disconnecting extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getText(
                    R.string.disconnecting));
            progressDialog.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

             CommunicationManager.getInstance().Disconnecting(
                    params[0]);

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);




                progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }


 private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String lostId = intent.getStringExtra("ID");

            System.out.println("LOST ID" + lostId);




        }
    };
```

I think this problem is related to multitasking.When control is in broadcast receiver(more time spent in receiver), async task progress dialog is not dismissed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.I had declared progress dialog has global so there was a problem in dismissing.Now I declared the dialog within async task, it worked..progress dialog is getting dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

use like this to dismiss progress bar:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (p_dialog != null && p_dialog.isShowing())
        p_dialog.dismiss();
                {//To do task...
                 }
```